# php with preg_match_all() generates no results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use this php script in order to locate a stock quote from yahoo finance. The problem I'm having is that when the script is run it generates no results. This leads me to believe that my regular expression is incorrect, but when I use the same regex on myregextester.com it shows the results that I expect with the given input. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Also, my php may be incorrect for what I'm trying to do.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stock Quote from Nasdaq</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // choose stock to look at
        $symbol = 'AMZN';
        echo "<h1> Stock Quote for $symbol </h1>";
        //echo 'this printed (1)<br />';

        $theurl = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AMZN';

        //echo 'this printed (2)<br />';

        $contents = file_get_contents($theurl);

        //find the part of the page we want and output it
        if (preg_match_all('/amzn">([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $contents, $matches)) {
            echo "The price for $symbol: ".$matches[1][0];
        } else {
            echo "No Results";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dude, when it comes to regex, always start with a small text example and test it a lot.

Comment: What gets output when you run this script? It's possible Yahoo is returning something different to your script than they return to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is:

```
 <span id="yfs_l10_amzn">221.37</span>
```

Your regex would succeed for that.

So your actual problem is retrieving the page. Besides the obnoxious `$theurl` variable name, you should just use `file_get_contents` instead of `fread` etc.

```
 $contents = file_get_contents($theurl);
```

Worked in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the url http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AMZN and looked at the page source. Done a seach for /amzn. One match. That was `<a href="/marketpulse/AMZN">Market Pul....` Hence no match.

Need to have a rethink.

Comment: The regex keeps looking on until it also finds the specified decimals.

Comment: @mario - no it does not. After finding the amzn the next characters should be "> followed by digits. Just look at the page source. I just chose the first few characters of the regex to do the search.

Comment: That's not the only occurence. Again, if the regex doesn't match, PCRE keeps on searching for the next partial match. Btw, the `/` is delimiter, not part of the regex; and it was neither case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the >

try this:

```
preg_match_all('/amzn"\>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$contents, $matches);
```